# Using python variables in jmespath.search

Tags: python-3.x, jmespath

I am working on a script to query instances not running an AMI. Below query works

```
print(jmespath.search(
    "Reservations[].Instances[?ImageId != `ami-056c679fab9e48d8a`].{ InstanceName: Tags[?Key == `Name`]|[0].Value, ImageId: ImageId, PrivateDNSName: PrivateDnsName, PrivateIpAddress: PrivateIpAddress}",
    response
))
```

I would like to use a variable instead. Like below. What's the recommended way to do variable substitution?

```
image_id="ami-056c679fab9e48d8a"
print(jmespath.search(
    "Reservations[].Instances[?ImageId != `{image_id}`].{ InstanceName: Tags[?Key == `Name`]|[0].Value, ImageId: ImageId, PrivateDNSName: PrivateDnsName, PrivateIpAddress: PrivateIpAddress}",
    response
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple string formatting, e.g. with [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (since Python 3.6):

```py
image_id = "ami-056c679fab9e48d8a"
print(jmespath.search(
    f"Reservations[].Instances[?ImageId != `{image_id}`].{{ InstanceName: Tags[?Key == `Name`]|[0].Value, ImageId: ImageId, PrivateDNSName: PrivateDnsName, PrivateIpAddress: PrivateIpAddress}}",
    response
))
```

You have to escape curly braces by duplicating them because they're otherwise used to insert variables.

Comment: One more question, if not matched it prints empty arrays like below. Is there a way filter out null or just print []?
```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: You mean the result of `jmespath.search()` is empty? Then don't print it right away - save it in a variable and check its content before printing it out.

Comment: I fixed it.
`parsed_list = [x for x in json_data if x]`